# What are the advantages of explicitly setting up relationships inside of a database

Tags: mysql, database-design, relation

When your creating a database schema and come up with all the foreign keys. What are the advantages of explicitly defining them as such in the database?

Are there advantages?

If it's reliant MySQL is the db I will be using.

Comment: MySQL does not mean much unless you specify the database engine you are going yo use. Some of MySql dbe do not have referential integrity, meaning they are not relational.

Comment: @Patrick. Whether a DBMS supports referential integrity constraints has nothing to do with whether it is relational or not. It's just that RI is a useful type of constraint to have in a relational database. Some people misunderstand the term "relational" to mean to "relationships between tables" but that's certainly not what it means at all.

Comment: @dportas: a database is relational if it supports most of Edgar Codd's 12 rules. Afaik, referential integrity is an essential part of it, otherwise it is just a "marketing relational" database, like old dBase.

Comment: @Patrick: Codd's 13 rules say nothing about requiring foreign keys, but anyway they are nothing like a definition. The 13 are really just observations about some properties of DBMSs and were written 20 years after relational databases were invented. An RDBMS is one whose data structures are relations, hence the name (mathworld.wolfram.com/Relation.html). That has nothing to do with RI constraints. I don't have anything against RI constraints of course - they are a good thing. But RI does not make a DBMS relational and the absence of it does not stop it being relational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are used for maintaining [Referential Integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) which is a database constraint that ensures that references between data are indeed valid and intact (a database should not only store data but should also ensure its quality). In other words, they help to ensure that relationships between tables remain consistent. From Wikipedia:

> **Referential integrity** is a property of data which, when
>   satisfied, requires every value of one
>   attribute (column) of a relation
>   (table) to exist as a value of another
>   attribute in a different (or the same)
>   relation (table).
>
> Less formally, and in relational
>   databases: For referential integrity
>   to hold, any field in a table that is
>   declared a foreign key can contain
>   only values from a parent table's
>   primary key or a candidate key. For
>   instance, deleting a record that
>   contains a value referred to by a
>   foreign key in another table would
>   break referential integrity. Some
>   relational database management systems
>   (RDBMS) can enforce referential
>   integrity, normally either by deleting
>   the foreign key rows as well to
>   maintain integrity, or by returning an
>   error and not performing the delete.
>   Which method is used may be determined
>   by a referential integrity constraint
>   defined in a data dictionary.
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>
> An example of a database that has not
>   enforced referential integrity. In
>   this example, there is a foreign key
>   (artist_id) value in the album table
>   that references a non-existent artist
>   — in other words there is a foreign
>   key value with no corresponding
>   primary key value in the referenced
>   table. What happened here was that
>   there was an artist called
>   "Aerosmith", with an artist_id of "4",
>   which was deleted from the artist
>   table. However, the album "Eat the
>   Rich" referred to this artist. With
>   referential integrity enforced, this
>   would not have been possible.

In order to create a foreign key between two tables with MySQL, **both tables need to be InnoDB tables** (with the default MyISAM table type, you can "define" a foreign key but they do not actually do anything).

Answer (score 3):

Data integrity - the constraint helps ensure that the data in different tables is consistent. A side benefit is that constraints are available to the DBMS's query optimizer which will help it to optimise the performance of some queries.

Answer (score 2):

When you properly define primary/foreign key relationships, the database handles enforcing referential integrity. You won't be allowed to insert data that violates the restrictions you've specified at the database level.